# Can't increment variable in Swift - not throwing any errors

Tags: swift, increment

(I'm very new to programming, so layman-friendly answers are certainly appreciated)

I'm working on a game played with two teams. I have a button that does a check for which team is up and then updates that team's score. The code runs with no errors but the score doesn't update when the button is pressed.

In my model file I declare

```
var teamOneScore = 0
var teamTwoScore = 0
var teamCounter = 2
```

In the view controller I have

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if timer.valid && teamCounter % 2 == 0 {
        ++teamOneScore
    } else if timer.valid && teamCounter % 2 != 0 {
        ++teamTwoScore
    }
}
```

In viewDidLoad

```
        if teamCounter % 2 == 0 {
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(teamOneScore)"
    } else {
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(teamTwoScore)"
    }
```

When the view loads, scoreLabel correctly displays 0, but when I press the button, the displayed score doesn't go up. The timer and teamCounter checks are working fine everywhere else in the code and I have another button that increments teamCounter (which is also stored as an int in the model) with no problems. So all the separate components of buttonPressed seem to be working fine and I don't have any errors to go on. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the text setting in an extra method. Right now the text only gets set in viewDidLoad - that function will not be triggered more than once however.

change your viewDidLoad to something like

```
updateUI()
```

add a new function

```
func updateUI() {
    if teamCounter % 2 == 0 {
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(teamOneScore)"
    } else {
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(teamTwoScore)"
    }
}
```

and call that method as the last thing in the button action:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if timer.valid && teamCounter % 2 == 0 {
        ++teamOneScore
    } else if timer.valid && teamCounter % 2 != 0 {
        ++teamTwoScore
    } 
    updateUI()
}
```

Comment: Fixed. Thank you! I decided to add the text update to my buttonPressed function. Would there be an advantage to creating a separate, new function like you describe here?

Comment: it would unite the initial display of the text and any future changes - for example if you want to display a different text you would not have to change it in viewDidLoad *and* in the buttonPressed.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `scoreLabel` in `viewDidLoad`, you assign it a text value of `"Score: \(teamOneScore)"` which is great.  However, when you increment the `teamOneScore` variable, the actual `UILabel` does not know to change its `text`.  It assumes you wanted to display `Score: 0`.  Even if a variable changed its value, that label has already been created and will continue to display whatever text was initialized.

What you need to do in your `buttonPressed` function is add

`scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(teamOneScore)"` or
`scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(teamOneScore)"` if it was team 2 that scored.

after you increment the score.  This is what allows the label's text to actually change.

Comment: This clicked for me right after I hit submit on this question after hours of tinkering with the code. Doh! Thank you for a prompt, accurate and courteous reply.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  If this has sufficiently solved the problem you can mark an answer as "correct".  This will help future users and will also alert other responders that the question has been answered :)

Comment: @luk2302 's method is also very helpful and may be an even better implementation because it gives you a function you can use anywhere.